# Error message in R: attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions

Tags: r, error-handling, constraints

I have code that works when I don't put too much constraints on it. However, I want to run the large amount of constraints. Is there anyway to help solve the problem, or work around this error. I'm trying to plot a efficient frontier. Thanks. I have dput for data timeseries below.

```
library("fPortfolio")
library('fPortfolio')
data = SPISECTOR.RET
asset = dim(data)[2]

# I'm putting a lot of constraints here. I want to do this. 
# If I take away some of the constraints, the formula works. 
# But I don't want to take away the constraints.
constraints <- c('minW[1:asset]=0','maxW[1:asset]=0.3', 'minsumW[c("ACWI", "ACWX", "AGED", "CEMA", "CEMG", "CMXC", "CNYA", "COMF", "CSJP", "CSKR", "CSRU", "CSUK", "DGTL", "DLTM", "ECAR", "EEM", "EFA", "EIDO", "EIRL", "EMB", "ENOR", "EPHE", "EPOL", "EUSA", "GUNR", "HEAL", "ICDU", "ICSU", "IESU", "IGAA", "IH2O", "IHCU", "IHYA", "IIND", "IISU", "IITU", "IJS", "IJT", "IMSU", "INRG", "IQLT", "IUSU", "KWEB", "LAND", "LOCK", "MGK", "OPEN", "QQQ", "RBOT", "SAUS", "SPAG", "UIFS", "UNG", "USMV", "VB", "VNQ", "VNQI", "VTV", "VUG", "WOOD", "XFVT")]=0.01', 'maxsumW[c("ACWI", "ACWX", "AGED", "CEMA", "CEMG", "CMXC", "CNYA", "COMF", "CSJP", "CSKR", "CSRU", "CSUK", "DGTL", "DLTM", "ECAR", "EEM", "EFA", "EIDO", "EIRL", "EMB", "ENOR", "EPHE", "EPOL", "EUSA", "GUNR", "HEAL", "ICDU", "ICSU", "IESU", "IGAA", "IH2O", "IHCU", "IHYA", "IIND", "IISU", "IITU", "IJS", "IJT", "IMSU", "INRG", "IQLT", "IUSU", "KWEB", "LAND", "LOCK", "MGK", "OPEN", "QQQ", "RBOT", "SAUS", "SPAG", "UIFS", "UNG", "USMV", "VB", "VNQ", "VNQI", "VTV", "VUG", "WOOD", "XFVT")]=0.3', 'minsumW[c("BND", "CBON", "CRPA", "GLD", "SLV", "SPGP", "SWAN")]=0.01', 'maxsumW[c("BND", "CBON", "CRPA", "GLD", "SLV", "SPGP", "SWAN")]=0.3', 'minsumW[c("GLTL", "GLTS", "IBGE", "IBGY", "IBGZ", "IEF", "IGLT", "SEGA", "SHY", "TIP", "TLT", "VVUILG")]=0.01', 'maxsumW[c("GLTL", "GLTS", "IBGE", "IBGY", "IBGZ", "IEF", "IGLT", "SEGA", "SHY", "TIP", "TLT", "VVUILG")]=0.3')

spec <- portfolioSpec()
setNFrontierPoints(spec) <- 25
setSolver(spec)<- "solveRquadprog"

frontier <-portfolioFrontier(data, spec, constraints)
```

when I run the last line, `frontier <-portfolioFrontier(data, spec, constraints)` I get the error:

```
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = names(getMu(Data))) : 
attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

Comment: So if you don't mind some comments, first it would be helpful to name the package you are using. Second, is this really the smallest possible example you could create? Remember people are copying your code.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have to set some more values for spec?

Comment: I get an error earlier, on `setNFrontierPoints(spec) <- 25` I installed the `fPortfolio` package, but find no function with `??setNFrontierPoints`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got it working. I didn't add the constraints up to one, and I put in other libraries. Everything is okay now.

Answer (score 0):

What caused me the same error in generating two-asset lines was due to careless coding in `portfolioFrontier()` that could not identify the efficient-portfolio solution due to double floating point precision issues, if any asset in a pair has a negative average return. To find the interior solution, internal coding of `portfolioFrontier()` introduces a tolerance term, `.Machine$double.eps`, intended to adjust the target return exclusively within the limits formed by the average return of each asset. But the way the function definition script prescribes the adjusting factor to shrink the solution boundaries only when both assets have positive average returns. If any of them have negative returns, however, the adjusting factor expands the target return beyond each assets' average return, making the problem unsolvable. This leads to an empty weight matrix `NULL` returned, resulting in a error when assigned column names from asset data.

The solution is to change two lines in the script of the function as follows, making the adjusting factor depend on the sign of the asset return.

```r
portfolioFrontier <- function (
    data, spec = portfolioSpec(), constraints = "LongOnly", 
    include.mvl = TRUE, title = NULL, description = NULL) {
  DEBUG <- TRUE
  fPortfolio:::.checkSpecVsConstraints(spec, constraints)
  Data <- portfolioData(data, spec)
  nFrontierPoints = getNFrontierPoints(spec)
  mu <- getMu(Data)
  targetReturns <- seq(min(mu), max(mu), length = nFrontierPoints)
  eps <- .Machine$double.eps^0.5 
  # !!! changed below
  targetReturns[1] = targetReturns[1] * (1 + sign(targetReturns[1]) * eps)
  targetReturns[nFrontierPoints] = targetReturns[nFrontierPoints] * 
    (1 - sign(targetReturns[nFrontierPoints]) *eps) # make less extreme
  mvPortfolio <- minvariancePortfolio(Data, spec, constraints)
  mvReturn <- getTargetReturn(mvPortfolio@portfolio)["mean"]
  minIndex <- which.min(abs(mvReturn - targetReturns))
  Status <- 0
  IDX <- minIndex
  weights <- targetReturn <- targetRisk <- covRiskBudgets <- maxDD <- NULL
  while (Status == 0 & IDX <= nFrontierPoints) {
    setTargetReturn(spec) = targetReturns[IDX]
    ans = try(efficientPortfolio(Data, spec, constraints), silent = TRUE)
    if (inherits(ans, "try-error")) {Status = 1} else {
      portfolio = ans
      Status = getStatus(portfolio)
    }
    if (Status == 0) {
      Weights = getWeights(portfolio)
      weights = rbind(weights, Weights)
      targetReturn = rbind(
        targetReturn, getTargetReturn(portfolio@portfolio))
      targetRisk = rbind(
        targetRisk, getTargetRisk(portfolio@portfolio))
      covRiskBudgets = rbind(
        covRiskBudgets, getCovRiskBudgets(portfolio@portfolio))
    }
    IDX = IDX + 1
  }
  if (include.mvl) {
    if (minIndex > 1) {
      weights2 = targetReturn2 = targetRisk2 = covRiskBudgets2 = maxDD2 = NULL
      Status = 0
      IDX = minIndex - 1
      while (Status == 0 & IDX > 0) {
        setTargetReturn(spec) = targetReturns[IDX]
        ans = try(efficientPortfolio(Data, spec, constraints), silent = TRUE)
        if (inherits(ans, "try-error")) {Status = 1} else {
          portfolio = ans
          Status = getStatus(portfolio) }
        if (Status == 0) {
          Weights2 = getWeights(portfolio)
          weights2 = rbind(Weights2, weights2)
          targetReturn2 = rbind(
            getTargetReturn(portfolio@portfolio), targetReturn2)
          targetRisk2 = rbind(
            getTargetRisk(portfolio@portfolio), targetRisk2)
          covRiskBudgets2 = rbind(
            getCovRiskBudgets(portfolio@portfolio), covRiskBudgets2)
        }
        IDX = IDX - 1
      }
      weights = rbind(weights2, weights)
      targetReturn = rbind(targetReturn2, targetReturn)
      targetRisk = rbind(targetRisk2, targetRisk)
      covRiskBudgets = rbind(covRiskBudgets2, covRiskBudgets)
    }
  }
  colnames(weights) <- names(getMu(Data))
  rownames(weights) <- NULL
  rownames(covRiskBudgets) <- NULL
  rownames(targetReturn) <- NULL
  rownames(targetRisk) <- NULL
  if (is.null(weights)) {
    portfolio <- mvPortfolio
    return(portfolio)
  }
  setTargetReturn(spec) <- NULL
  portfolio@call <- match.call()
  portfolio@portfolio <- new(
    "fPFOLIOVAL", portfolio = list(
      weights = weights, covRiskBudgets = covRiskBudgets, 
      targetReturn = targetReturn, targetRisk = targetRisk, 
      targetAlpha = getAlpha(spec), 
      minriskPortfolio = mvPortfolio, status = 0))
  portfolio@title = "Portfolio Frontier"
  portfolio
}
```

Create this function object in the console, then use is in place of the original `portfolioFrontier()` from the {fPortfolio} package.